# building project "INSTALL.vcxproj" -- FAILED

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake, opencv, python

I am trying to setup OpenCV in the MS Visual Studio Code 2019 through CMake.

Open CV version = 4.1.2

While running the build for the INSTALL it is giving the following error.

"Done building project "INSTALL.vcxproj" -- FAILED."

Following are the detailed error messages.

```
2>-- Installing: C:/Users/adity/repos/darknet/build/install/include/opencv2/stitching/detail/seam_finders.hpp
2>-- Installing: C:/Users/adity/repos/darknet/build/install/include/opencv2/stitching/detail/timelapsers.hpp
2>-- Installing: C:/Users/adity/repos/darknet/build/install/include/opencv2/stitching/detail/util.hpp
2>-- Installing: C:/Users/adity/repos/darknet/build/install/include/opencv2/stitching/detail/util_inl.hpp
2>-- Installing: C:/Users/adity/repos/darknet/build/install/include/opencv2/stitching/detail/warpers.hpp
2>-- Installing: C:/Users/adity/repos/darknet/build/install/include/opencv2/stitching/detail/warpers_inl.hpp
2>-- Installing: C:/Users/adity/repos/darknet/build/install/x64/vc16/lib/opencv_superres412.lib
2>-- Installing: C:/Users/adity/repos/darknet/build/install/x64/vc16/bin/opencv_superres412.dll
2>-- Installing: C:/Users/adity/repos/darknet/build/install/include/opencv2/superres.hpp
2>-- Installing: C:/Users/adity/repos/darknet/build/install/include/opencv2/superres/optical_flow.hpp
2>CMake Error at modules/python3/cmake_install.cmake:44 (file):
2>  file cannot create directory: C:/Program
2>  Files/WindowsApps/PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0/Lib/site-packages/cv2.
2>  Maybe need administrative privileges.
2>Call Stack (most recent call first):
2>  modules/cmake_install.cmake:170 (include)
2>  cmake_install.cmake:125 (include)
2>
2>
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: The command "setlocal
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -DBUILD_TYPE=Release -P cmake_install.cmake
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: :cmEnd
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: :cmErrorLevel
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: exit /b %1
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: :cmDone
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 1.
2>Done building project "INSTALL.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 148 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: It should be more detailed message(s) about that fail. Without that information we cannot help you.

Comment: What else shall I include

Answer (score 0):

run Visual Studio with administrative privileges. it will succeed with no errors